# Is there a cockpit indication if the B737 flap load relief is not working properly?

Tags: boeing-737, flaps, cockpit-alerts

On a 737, does the pilot get any cockpit indication that his Flap Load Relief is not working properly? Say for instance due to a Flap Lever Position Switch failure?

Comment: By what sequence of cause & effect do you expect a failure of a switch related to the position of the flap handle to manifest itself as a failure of the Load Relief system? The latter system doesn't do anything until you're about to overspeed the flaps (so, it activates pretty rarely), but a problem with the flap lever should be obvious during normal operations.

Answer (score 2):

The cockpit indication would be that the flaps don't retract as expected. The subsequent flap overspeed would then be captured by the Flight Data Recorder, the same as any other exceedance. But I'm unaware of any specific indication on a cockpit display that indicates directly "the Flap Load Relief isn't working".

Answer (score 0):

If a (minimal) flap skew is detected, all 737 will display a 15 degree difference in flap position.
If the automatic flap load limitation engages, a FLAP LOAD RELIEF light illuminates right above the flap gauge. The limiter is on all 737, the light only on some types.

Comment: Can you document this? Can't recall ever seeing such a "Flap Load Relief" light ever mentioned in the manuals I've seen.   Separately, what does the first sentence about skew have to do with the OP's question?

Comment: @RalphJ The FLAP LOAD RELIEF light exists in my 737 NG FCOM, but it is listed as an option. However, it illuminates when flap load relief occurs normally, **not** when there is a problem with the flap load relief system, so this doesn't really answer the question.